# how to Import a code library in mirth which is running on linux server

Tags: linux, server, mirth

Im using mirth version 3.11 on linux server.

I wants to import code libraries but im unable to do it. every time im trying to import im getting following error.

I tried to write it manually still mirth is not allowing to add any code library at all.

[image]

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved, the error message in text form, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the error message is a bit generic. What you can do:

1. Test it on your local Mirth
2. Replicate the error by simulating the environment of your Mirth in a linux server.
3. Possible that there are permission restriction that does not allow you to make changes on Mirth configuration. Try running the Mirth Connect Administrator with a higher permission.